# jQuery loads spontaneously on first page visit but not on refresh in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a low-tech messaging system between users in my rails application.  I've noticed that, inexplicably, my app loads random messages when I go to another link and then back to the page in question even though it's totally wrapped inside of an on( "click", ... ) event.  I have no idea why my app is loading the users before I've even clicked anything, let alone why it's loading these seemingly random messages.  It's like jQuery is just being spontaneous on load but acts perfectly on refresh.  I have a feeling this either has to do with my browsers cache or sprockets.  Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Just a capitalization helper.
  String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
      return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
  }

  // Clears out data and fills in with fresh Ajax
  function getMessages () {
    $('.message-section').children().remove();
    var $senders_id = this.id
    $username = $(this).attr( "data-username" )

    function messageBuilder(message){
      if ($senders_id == message.senders_id){
        console.log(message.senders_id);
        var $usernameDiv = $('<div class="col-12-xs">From: ' + $username.capitalize() + '</div>');
        var $messageDiv = $('<div class="col-12-xs message-div">Message: ' + message.note + '</div>');
        var $messageReply = $('<a href="#">Reply</a><hr>');
        $('.message-section').append($usernameDiv);
        $('.message-section').append($messageDiv);
        $('.message-section').append($messageReply);
      }
    }

    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/messages',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          data.forEach(function(message) {
            messageBuilder(message);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // The click event that sets it all off
  $('.messages-from').on( "click", getMessages );

});
```

For some reason everything works fine except for on the first visit to the page.  It works ok on refresh or when I click the items in question, but on the first visit, it just sort of pukes up all the messages.  I even tried adding this in immediately at the top line, under the document.ready part:

```
$('.message-section').children().remove();
```

So that it's present twice, once on click and once immediately after loading...Still, the result is the same.  The same freakish behavior when I go to the page for the first time, many messages sort of randomly coughed up from the app, even though I didn't click anything.  Here's what my application.js looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

I've also noticed that if I remove the document.ready portion and just put everything on the global scope absolutely nothing happens, maybe this is a clue?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be `turbolinks`. Try removing it.

Comment: Absolutely, unexrquivicobaly + exquisitely 100% right!